# Automatic Internationalization Testing For Web

Tags: testing, internationalization

Does there exist a website service or set of scripts that will tell you whether your web page badly configured if your goal is to be internationally friendly?

To be more precise, I'm wondering if something like this exists:

```
Checking URL: http://www.example.com
GET / HTTP/1.0
Accept-Charset: utf8
...

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Charset: iso-8859-1
..<?xml version="1.0" charset="utf8" ?>

WARNING: Header document conflict, your server claims to return iso-8859-1, but
includes octet values outside the legal range.  This can happen when your documents
are saved with a different character set than your web server is configured to serve.
```

From my understanding its unlikely that this will help me make a website that will allow people to post in Japanese or Hebrew, but it might be able to help my English websites reach a larger international audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) does it, but maybe not to the extent you are looking for...